# Storing a Full Name in a custom Data Extension from an Info Capture response

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

We are trying to store a full name response from an Info Capture message into a custom data extension via AMPScript. We decided to use this approach instead of adding a new attribute to the MobileConnect Demographics table or having the response ask them a question for first then last name.

Example Code:

```
%%[
    set @response = v( [MSG(0).NOUN(0)] )
    set @response = Replace( @response , 'KEYWORD ' )
    set @mobileNumber = MOBILE_NUMBER
    InsertData( 'DE_NAME', 'Name', @response, 'MobileNumber', @mobileNumber )
]%%
```

I tried removing the Replace from the example code I found and using the below code. However, it still populates the Keyword as the name instead of my name response.

```
%%[
    set @response = v( [MSG(0)] )
    set @mobileNumber= MOBILE_NUMBER
    InsertData( 'DE_NAME', 'Name', @response, 'MobileNumber', @mobileNumber )
]%%
```

I have also tried searching for the next value in the MSG array using:

```
set @response = v( [MSG(1)] )
```

However this returns blank and I'm assuming that is because MSG(0) is pulling the Keyword and the MSG array doesn't actually pick up the second response as a name.

Also trying an UpsertData instead of InsertData keeps giving me the error response instead of taking any input from the message.

Is there something simple I'm missing on this approach or is this not possible with AMPScript and the Info Capture template?